# Set sequelize model primaryKey type in CLI

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

how can we set our own `primaryKey` & AutoIncrement column Type to avoid default ID that sequelize generator generates?

i tried

```
npx sequelize --name User --attributes nationalCode{type:integer,autoIncrement:false,PrimaryKey:true},
firstName:string,lastName:string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set names and data types only. See [Model template](https://github.com/sequelize/cli/blob/master/src/assets/models/model.js) in sequelize-cli rep.

Comment: Thanks for Answer, do u mean to edit that generated Model.js? that CLI generates? or sth else? when i change my model file, after that when i migrate it doesn't migrate and say that migration is up to date ...

Comment: Ypu should correct both your model and your migration.